# Problem of serializing javascript object to JSON string

Tags: javascript, json

My question is sort of stupid that why

```
JSON.stringify({"annotation": [{"x":1, "y":2}, {"x":1, "y":2}]})
```

does not return

```
{"annotation": [{"x": 1, "y": 2}, {"x": 1, "y": 2}]}
```

but returns

```
{"annotation":"[{\"x\": 1, \"y\": 2}, {\"x\": 1, \"y\": 2}]"}
```

and how can I get the first output?

Comment: In which browser are you having this behavior?. If it's a browser with no *native JSON* support, which library are you using?

Comment: I'm using the widely used library from, http://www.json.org/json2.js. This seems to be Prototype's conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Prototype? This question may be related:

[JSON.stringify() array bizarreness with Prototype.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710586/json-stringify-bizarreness)

Comment: I have had this problem without using Prototype.