# Retrieving json array with $.ajax GET to php

Tags: php, jquery, json

I must be making some simple error somewhere, any help appreciated.

Associative Array

```
data_form[name] = value;
```

Action

```
$.ajax({
    type:       "GET",
    cache:      false,
    url:        "../pages/ajax/takeaction.php",
    data:       ({ json: JSON.stringify(data_form) }),
    success: function(data) {
        var message = "Your information has been received!";

        $('.element').html(message)
             .hide()
             .fadeIn(1500, function() {                 
                $(this).append("<br/>"+data)});
    }

});
```

This is what the JSON.stringify data string ends up as

```
{"action":"register","username":"","email":"","password":"","password2":"","max":"5000000","userfile":""}
```

Then my php file action

```
$json = $_GET["json"];
```

Gets it and has value

```
{\"action\":\"register\",\"username\":\"\",\"email\":\"\",\"password\":\"\",\"password2\":\"\",\"max\":\"5000000\",\"userfile\":\"\"}
```

Then try to decode and it returns nothing (using php array foreach etc)

```
   $array = json_decode($json, true);
```

Comment: What do you return if you print_r($array)?  Just tested your string locally and it populates the array no problem.  So this suggests it might be a problem with the foreach.

Comment: @simnom it prints absolutely nothing.

Comment: Just a note, i found that type "GET" has a limit to it, using post works better for this load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have both jQuery and Prototype included? If so, take a look at [JSON.stringify() array bizarreness with Prototype.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710586/json-stringify-bizarreness/3148441#3148441).

On second thought it looks less like that and more like you have [magic_quotes_gpc](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc) set to On in php.ini.

Comment: yeah i do have magic_quotes enabled, would that be causing the decode to fail?

Comment: I string replaced the escape char '\' and the decode is working.