# Twitter Bootstrap modal slides down and fades in, but upon close, it immediately closes, it does not do a slide up fade out transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, prototype, bootstrap-modal

The modal works fine, but when you try to close it, it doesn't do the same slide up fade out animation as the demo on the bootstrap javascript page.

I did some debugging and in my version, when it hits $this.element.trigger(e);, it immediately closes the popup.  However in bootstrap's demo version, it reaches $this.element.trigger(e), it has no effect on screen and reaches $.supportTransition, and once it hits hideWithTransition(), it slides up and fades out like its supposed to.

Anybody have any idea whats going on? Thank you for any help.

modal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" style="display: none;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-target="myModal" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
  <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal Heading</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <h4>Text in a modal</h4>
  <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem.</p>

  <h4>Popover in a modal</h4>
  <p>This <a href="#" role="button" class="btn popover-test" title="A Title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?">button</a> should trigger a popover on click.</p>

  <h4>Tooltips in a modal</h4>
  <p><a href="#" class="tooltip-test" title="Tooltip">This link</a> and <a href="#" class="tooltip-test" title="Tooltip">that link</a> should have tooltips on hover.</p>

  <hr>

  <h4>Overflowing text to show optional scrollbar</h4>
  <p>We set a fixed <code>max-height</code> on the <code>.modal-body</code>. Watch it overflow with all this extra lorem ipsum text we've included.</p>
  <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
  <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
  <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
  <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
  <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
  <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>

</div>
```

anchor modal trigger:

```
<a role="button" data-toggle="modal"  href="#myModal" title="<?php echo $_link->getTitle() ?>" <?php echo $_link->getAParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></a>
```

I forgot to mention that I am using this with a magento site. I'm using magento community edition 1.7.0.2.  There must be a conflict somewhere, otherwise it should work. I'll try a jsfiddle.

**UPDATE!**

Ok, I found the culprit.  I removed the prototype script that I'm using with Jquery in noconflict mode. Once I removed prototype it worked fine.  Anyone have any idea why that would happen with prototype? I'm going to continue trying to find out.  Thanks.

Comment: Post your code please!

Comment: The posted code works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/jasny/6Wh6a/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem after debugging.  When I step through the hide method of the bootstrap modal plugin, it calls prototypes hide method:

```
Element.Methods = {
  hide: function(element) {
    element = $(element);
    element.style.display = 'none';
    return element;
},
```

The stack trace shows that in jQuery.event.trigger, there is a statement:

```
elem[type]();
```

, and this calls prototypes version of "methodize()", and when it does the statement

```
 __method.apply(), it calls prototypes hide function.
```

See this related stackoverflow question, which helped me solve my problem [popover-hides-parent-element-if-used-with-prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087129/popover-hides-parent-element-if-used-with-prototype-js)

All I had to do was rename the $.Event('hide') to $.Event('something_else')

Comment: how would i go about fixing this?