# Make Bootstrap Dropdown work in Magento / with prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, twitter-bootstrap, prototype

I try to get Bootstrap work together with Magento. Magento is using prototype and this causes a little bit trouble.
My problem is that the Bootstrap dropdown is not working correct.
I already found and tested this solution:
[Twitter Bootstrap 3 dropdown menu disappears when used with prototype.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139063/twitter-bootstrap-3-dropdown-menu-disappears-when-used-with-prototype-js)

But I'm not satisfied with this solution because it changes the prototype source of Magento and i don't want to do that.
Thats why I'm searching for a better solution.

In this fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/T88ak/

```
jQuery(function(){
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery('#dropdown-toggle').on('click',function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        jQuery('#dropdown-menu').toggle();
    });
});
```

I recreated the problem.

Now I'm trying to find a solution to repair bootstrap or prototype without touching the source code.
A little code snippet which I have to include in my library would be fine. But I'm struggling with a solution.

Maybe another jQuery Ninja in this forum can help me?

Regards
Benjamin

Comment: Try adding this at the end of your jquery file. `jQuery.noConflict()`

Comment: I use jQuery noConflicht already. I even use it in the code in this post.

Comment: Yep. Apparently I cannot read. Sorry for that. Ignore me for now

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using below code and add jquery.noConlict() to your jQuery library.and add jQuery library to top of all js/prototype

```
jQuery.noConflict(); // if you haven't added it to your jquery library 
        jQuery(function($){
    $('#dropdown-toggle').on('click',function(evt){
            evt.preventDefault();
            $('#dropdown-menu').toggle();
        });
    });
```