# bootstrap magento dropdown menu not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, magento

I am new to twitter bootstrap as well as with magento and I have a question,

I found this snippet of twitter bootstrap on http://wsnippets.com/create-mega-menu-navigation-bar-twitter-bootstrap-3-0/ and while I am trying to implement it in magento ( v.1.19) I fail.
this is the fiddle:

```
>  [http://jsfiddle.net/NHv35/6/][1]

 .
```

Basically the problem is that after a click on a category the drop-down works but after i click elsewhere the div is removed, it adds an inline style display:none; . How can I go around it?

the stranger problem is that in fiddle it works but on my local machine it doesn't.

Please help,
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

this problem is because of `prototype. js`. Check **hide** function in prototype.js, in this they have set display none on inline style.

follow this link to solve :

http://kk-medienreich.at/techblog/magento-bootstrap-integration-mit-prototype-framework/

[Twitter Bootstrap 3 dropdown menu disappears when used with prototype.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139063/twitter-bootstrap-3-dropdown-menu-disappears-when-used-with-prototype-js)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">` top of your document and enjoy :)

Comment: Ohh, I have checked the fiddle there also I couldn't see any drop-down. Could you please explain about that

Comment: Have you tried to render your page on server instead of checking it on local. And one more thing I want to ask on which browser you are checking it.

Comment: I am checking it on firefox

Comment: I can only run it locally I dont have a server at my disposal.

Comment: well,  this I am kind of new to this twitter bootstrap, i said i copied the snippet from online. I drops down but afterwords it disappears from the page.