# bootstrap: style="display:none" get's automatically appended in the 'li'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have following piece of code in my jsp.

```
<li id="report" class="dropdown open"><a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Report <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li ><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
              <li style=""><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

but when it's getting rendered in the browser, automatically the code becomes as following:

```
<li id="report" class="dropdown open"><a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Report <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li style="display: none;"><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li style="display: none;"><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li style="display: none;"><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider" style="display: none;"></li>
              <li class="nav-header" style="display: none;">Nav header</li>
              <li style="display: none;"><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li style="display: none;"><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I am unable to understand from where all the li's are getting this style="display:none" property, is it some bootstrap javascript which is doing it. I am debugging the code on chrome.

Comment: It's not from core Bootstrap JS. I would guess it's some custom jQuery code you have written.

Comment: It's because of bootstrap js file

Comment: I can't reproduce this with bootstrap3 [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/zeNdC/)

Comment: @A1rPun I am using bootstrap2.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with bootstrap2 [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/SLy4A/)

Comment: @HenriHietala is there any way I can know, exactly which query is executing on my corresponing li's.

Comment: @A1rPun You can't reproduce this because you have using the html which I wrote in jsp, but the html which is getting rendered in the browser is something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/SLy4A/1/

Comment: @learner420 Try to comment out your scripts one by one and narrow it down to the right piece of code.

Comment: @HenriHietala thanks Henri, have to go now from the office see you tomorow, thanks everyone..

Comment: @learner420 What I was trying to say is this is not behavior from bootstrap itself..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to track, which js was doing the changes to my lists, so what I did is, I put every li in a class called 'visible' and in my  tag I put a style as follows:

```
<style>
.visible{

display:inline !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem happens in Magento (version 1.9 for me) and it's caused by an incompatibility between Protype JS library and jQuery. There is a fix [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32063800/1439760).

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly normal: the style is added in order to hide the dropdown menu when related button isn't clicked.
That control is performed by JavaScript (check `bootstrap.js`).

Comment: It must have been normal, if the bootstrap was changing the style of every li to display:none. But it need not to since all the li is contained inside a ul and the behaviour can be controlled from there. I can't post the images because I have less than 10 reputation sorry :(

Comment: If you need some customization, you have to declare another script that does what you want.