# bootstrap.js 2.3 is conflicting with magento's prototype.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, prototypejs

I'm facing a weird issue that is I've an accordion on given URL, problem is accordion is working fine but add to cart button has loose the functionality due to conflicting with bootstrap.js and magento's prototype.js. What should i do now?

http://etekstudio.org/demo/crateen/test-featured1

Comment: What have you tried? Did you add the noConflict() reference to the jQuery stuff? Have you seen this page which explains that? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: Take a look at this answer I provided to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/15095654/341491

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap.js replace

```
this.$element.trigger(startEvent);
```

with

```
this.$element.triggerHandler(startEvent);
```

it will work smoothly.