# Prototype, jQuery and Bootstrap cause tooltip elements to be hidden on mouse out

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, prototypejs

I've been working on a project using Prototype, jQuery and Bootstrap. We use Bootstrap Tooltips in our UI, normally over icons and text, as below:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Some tooltip"></span>

<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Another tooltip"></span>

<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Link tooltip">Link tooltip</a>
```

We then use some simple Javascript to activate our tooltip:

```
var _j = jQuery.noConflict();
_j("[data-toggle=\"tooltip\"]").tooltip();
```

I'm using `_j` alias of jQuery as the `$` prefix is used by Prototype. This works fine, but as soon as you move your mouse from a tooltip'd element, it has `style="display: hidden;` applied. I can't work out any reasonable explanation, so was wondering if anyone has any ideas?

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kJX7b/2/).

Comment: Make sure that Prototype loads before jQuery and jQuery.noConflict(). They have to be in that order. Your fiddle has them in a different order, but I don't know enough about fiddle to say for certain if that's possible to change. Your fiddle does work if I remove the Prototype framework entirely.

Comment: Take a look at my answer to another similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15095654/341491

Answer (score 0):

use this trick to solve the problem:

```
$('.tooltips').tooltip().on('hidden.bs.tooltip', function(){
     jQuery(this).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `display:block !important` within your CSS file. Doing this, it will force the element to show, even when the script is telling them to hide.