# Typo3 Jquery + Boostrap deletes elements

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, typo3

I'am using jQuery and Bootstrap in my TYPO3-Extension.

My HTML-Elements have an tooltip (bootstrap tooltip)

```
<input type="text" 
       class="form-control" 
       data-toggle="tooltip" 
       data-placement="bottom" 
       title="Nachname eingeben" 
       placeholder="Nachname" />
```

If I rollover the element --> Tooltip is shown correctly.

But if I rollout the element --> whole input element is deleted

The JS to the site is:

```
$.noConflict(); 
$(document).ready(function ($) { 
    // tooltips 
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
} );
```

whats the problem????

Comment: Asking "why isn't my code working" isn't helpful if all you've posted is boilerplate. Please post the issue in a way that can be replicated in order to provide better debugging assistance.

Comment: nothing to do with TYPO3, look at your JS

Comment: The JS to the site is:

`$.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    // tooltips
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();}
);`

Comment: resolved:

solution is:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087129/popover-hides-parent-element-if-used-with-prototype-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the next one who have a question like this, I put the answer gave by Felix himself here because it's more visible.

He finds the solution here : [Popover hides parent element if used with Prototype JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087129/popover-hides-parent-element-if-used-with-prototype-js)