# Angular JS $http.post method malforms JSON arrays

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, angularjs

**Hi SO.**

I have a weird problem that I've been struggling with all day long.

I have my Angular JS module (App), and a controller. In that controller, I inject a factory, which handles my $http.post method. (Which i call "doSearch"). So far so good.

On the back-end I have a spring-mvc rest api class. It looks like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/filesearch")
public class FileSearchAPI {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResultDTO doSearch(@RequestBody NewPerfectSearchDTO searchDTO) {
          System.out.println(searchDTO.getIdentifier());
          SolrService solrService = new SolrService();
          //return solrService.query(searchDTO);
          return new ResultDTO();
     }
}
```

And this is the function that sends some JSON, that will be mapped to a JAVA POJO/DTO:

```
doSearch: function(searchParams) {
        $http.post("/np/api/filesearch/search", JSON.stringify({identifier: "apa", inputRows: []})).success(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(status, headers, config);
        });
    }
```

Take note of the payload (Yes, it's static for this example):
`JSON.stringify({identifier: "apa", inputRows: []})`

This maps perfectly fine in my DTO. The fields are correct, and variable `inputRows` is an empty, initialized array.

**HOWEVER** when I look at the payload (Using firebug or the chrome inspector) , sent by the client, to the API,
it looks like this: `{"identifier":"apa","inputRows":"[]"}`

Did you notice the `""` around my JSON array?

```
{"identifier":"apa","inputRows":"[]"}
                                ^  ^
                                |  |
```

Yeah... That's the problem I'm having.
When I send that request, the server simply replies with a `HTTP 400`, malformed syntax (Tomcat/Spring error page), the request doesn't even invoke the APIController on the back-end.

So, what I've tried so far (without success):

- I have tried without using `JSON.stringify()` on the payload, with
  the same result
- I have tried specifying the headers in my APIController (No use, it doesn't even execute that code before throwing the error)
- I have tried using a `Java.util.List` instead of an array in the DTO

So I'm pretty much stuck here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As I suspected there may be interesting behavior of stringify: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710586/json-stringify-bizarreness

Comment: You can pass in the data as object, angularjs would serialize it itself. Try the method without using json.stringify

Comment: Please read the question again, I have stated that I have tried without JSON.stringify, but I still get the same result. @Chandermani

Comment: If i try to do `JSON.stringify({test:[]})` on browser console i get,`"{"test":[]}"`

Comment: Bare in mind that we're using AngularJS, and that it gives me the same result when I don't use JSON.stringify at all. I've tried using both Firefox, and Chrome (latest versions, ECMAscript 5). @Chandermani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have a conflicting prototype.js dependency overriding some functions.

I would try

```
delete Array.prototype.toJSON
```

before posting your object.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I hadn't checked if the old prototype.js was still included... It was. Thought it wasn't.