# JSON.stringify and non associative array

Tags: javascript, json

I want to serialize in json a non associative array and the output is quite disturbing

```
JSON.stringify([1]);
// Expected : "[1]"
Output : "\"[1]\""
```

It treats the array as a string, what am i missing ?

I'm using Chrome Version 29.0.1547.65

Comment: I ran into a similar issue when running my script on a third party site.  It turned out they had monkey-patched Array.prototype with a .toJSON() method.

Comment: This is exactly it ... How can i circumvent this issue ?

Comment: The answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710586/json-stringify-bizarreness) might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are seeing is because of an Array.prototype.toJSON method that has been defined incorrectly with respect to the semantics of JSON.stringify.  See below:

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

> toJSON behavior
>
> If an object being stringified has a property named toJSON whose value
>   is a function, then the toJSON method customizes JSON stringification
>   behavior: instead of the object being serialized, the value returned
>   by the toJSON method when called will be serialized.

When an object has a toJSON method the result of that method will be stringified in its place.  If the toJSON method is defined as a stringification then the object will be double stringified.

The only work-around I am aware of is to *remove* the method or to implement your own stringify() method with different semantics than the built-in.

If you can, simply remove the method from Array.prototype.  If you are concerned this will break other functionality on the page then you need to remove it, stringify, then restore it.

```
function myStringify( o ) {
    var temp = Array.prototype.toJSON;
    delete Array.prototype.toJSON;
    var result = JSON.stringify(o);
    Array.prototype.toJSON = temp;

    return result;
}
```