# JSON.stringify behaving different depending on two different pages context

Tags: javascript, json, phantomjs, casperjs, headless-browser

I am using CasperJS in order to crawl sites. I have found an interesting thing and I am not really sure why is it happening.

So, with CasperJS (and PhantomJS) you can get into the Page context, using their [Evaluate PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) [Evaluate CasperJS](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate) method.

I have created an object in the page context's, and in order to return it to the CasperJS I convert it to a string.  Here is what I do:

```
casper.then(function() {
    var test = this.evaluate(function() {
        var test_obj = { test_obj: ['test'] }
        console.log("TEST OBJECT VALUE:");
        var JSON_obj = JSON.stringify(test_obj);
        console.log(JSON_obj);
        return JSON_obj;
    });
});
```

So, in two different pages, the result is different:

When in this [page](http://www.dickssportinggoods.com/product/index.jsp?productId=23399126&cp=4406646.4413887.4414035.4414021.4418199.18320726.23894076) context, the JSON_obj value is:

```
{"test_obj":"[\"test\"]"}
```

When in this other [page](http://www.360skate.com/bones-super-reds-single-set-bearings) context, the JSON_obj value is:

```
{"test_obj":["test"]}
```

This is bad because I catch the results in Ruby, and when doing `JSON.parse`, for the first case it treats the array as a string... Any idea why `JSON.stringify` would behave "different" when in different page contexts? Interesting to me!

Comment: Probably the JSON object is not the same.

Comment: Isn't that native to JS though? Might be some library is overwritting? Agh!

Comment: Have you solved this issue with overwritten `stringify` implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be related to this problem - [JSON.stringify() array bizarreness with Prototype.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710586/json-stringify-array-bizarreness-with-prototype-js). When a site has Prototype.js framework installed then `JSON.stringify` may result in different string than you'd typically expect.