# How to convert array to proper JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array like this

```
product[0]['product_id']
product[0]['name']
....
product[1]['product_id']
product[1]['name']
...
```

When I use `JSON.stringify()`, I receive the following output

```
{"0":{"product_id":"1","name":"ABC"},"1":{"product_id":"1","name":"ABC"},...}
```

This is, however, not what I wanted to achieve because it doesn't preserver the array. Instead I want the JSON output to look like

```
[{"product_id":"1","name":"ABC"},{"product_id":"1","name":"ABC"},..]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that `product` is an array and not a general object. When I do the following

```
var product = []; // Array
product[0] = {product_id: 1, name: "name1"};
product[1] = {product_id: 2, name: "name2"};
```

then `JSON.stringify(product)` yields

```
"[{"product_id":1,"name":"name1"},{"product_id":2,"name":"name2"}]"
```

which is what you want to achieve.

I suspect that in your case `product` is a plain object meaning that `product[0]` accesses the property named `0` on the object and not the first element in an array. To illustrate this, consider the following snippet

```
var product = {}; // Plain JS object
product[0] = {product_id: 1, name: "name1"};
product[1] = {product_id: 2, name: "name2"};
```

When I run `JSON.stringify(product)` in this case, it results in the output you get

```
"{"0":{"product_id":1,"name":"name1"},"1":{"product_id":2,"name":"name2"}}"
```

If you're still experiencing issues, it might be worth trying the suggestion mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710586/json-stringify-array-bizarreness-with-prototype-js) which boils down to adding

```
delete Array.prototype.toJSON;
```

at the beginning of your script.

Comment: Help me! Please see my new post below.

Comment: @Diego Maybe it's worth trying to add `delete Array.prototype.toJSON;` to your code (see my updated answer).

Comment: Thank you so much. But nothing change. Maybe I will find some ways else :)