# JSON stringify behaving differently on two different chrome tabs

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

Can anybody help?

**Tab 1, chrome console, website: localhost:8080 (java application)**

```
var test = {  
    rowAttrs: ["asdf","asdf"]
}
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(test))
```

Result (unexpected):

```
Object {rowAttrs: "["asdf", "asdf"]"}
```

**Tab 2, chrome console, website: any**

```
var test = {  
    rowAttrs: ["asdf","asdf"]
}
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(test))
```

Result (as expected):

```
Object {rowAttrs: Array[2]}
```

Comment: They both mean the same thing. You can click on `Array[2]` and it will expand into `"["asdf", "asdf"]"`.

Comment: @RokNovosel: No, in the first one, `rowAttrs`'s value is a *string*.

Comment: We can't answer this question with just the information shown. Apparently, something in the `localhost:8080` website is overwriting the `JSON.stringify` and/or `JSON.parse` function with something that misbehaves. We can't tell you what that is, though.

Comment: thanks that was it, FYI http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710586/json-stringify-array-bizarreness-with-prototype-js

Comment: @T.J.Crowder , can you put your comment as an answer?

Comment: @SumamaWaheed: Wow! No need for an answer, you've found the question this duplicates. (Good find!)